# Why is this question marked as unanswered?

Tags: bug, unanswered-questions

[This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/239257/what-does-def-above-an-equals-sign-mean) is on the list of unanswered questions, even though it has an answer that has many upvotes (including, now, mine). Am I missing something or is this a bug of some kind?

EDIT  Here is a screen shot as of Dec 4, 2023 at 7:13 AM Eastern time

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: I’m not sure how the logic works for that feature but the Main Meta folks probably do.

Comment: @Sycorax, what does "post merge" in that concerned question mean? There is apparently an issue pertinent to this that has already been discussed at Meta: [Merged questions still show up in the Unanswered list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66068/merged-questions-still-show-up-in-the-unanswered-list).

Comment: Also the status was never completed: [Answered question with positive scored answer appearing in unanswered question list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284580/answered-question-with-positive-scored-answer-appearing-in-unanswered-question-l).

Comment: Questions that are exactly identical can be combined so that all the answers are in one place. We use it very rarely because it’s irreversible.

Comment: Which 'unanswered' list are we talking about? In the search function, I don't find it. Compare https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=What+def+means with https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=What+def+means+answers%3A0 is there maybe a screenshot of this?

Comment: Also in this list I do not find it: https://stats.stackexchange.com/unanswered has the status of the question been changed after recent activity?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus I was just using the list generated by clicking on "Unanswered" on the left side of the CrossValidated page.  I just did that again, and it's still there.  I took a screen shot  but it won't paste here for some reason. But if you click the button to sort by score, it's easy to find. I will try putting the screen shot in my question.

Comment: @PeterFlom it is weird that I do not get this to show up when I check it on my phone. Both in mobile mode and desktop mode.

Comment: I got it now. It depends indeed on the tab. The 'no answers' tab shows it correctly (and also seems to order by score) whereas the 'score' tab shows the mistake.